# Ionic 2 page jumps up and down in iOS when using ion-input

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I use this ionic version.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.2
Node Version: v7.4.0
```

Here's the code and its purpose is for the user to enter info and submit it.

```
<ion-content>

 <ion-list *ngIf="isTest">
 <ion-input> </ion-input>
 <ion-input> </ion-input>
 <ion-input> </ion-input>
 </ion-list>

 <button ion-button>Submit</button>
</ion-content>
```

On Android it's working, but when I test it on iOS, when I click on ion-input the page jumps up and down which is not good UX at all. Any ideas how to solve this issue on iOS ?

Here is video example of the issue. [drive.google.com/open?id=0B22-s3eK4PTLWXpNMk1tbzdjcGs](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B22-s3eK4PTLWXpNMk1tbzdjcGs)

Comment: Are you testing in a device? And what do you mean by jump up and down? can you share a picture with the initial and final state? By default the screen jumps because of the keyboard

Comment: Here is an example for my issue https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B22-s3eK4PTLWXpNMk1tbzdjcGs

Comment: So your code is exactly like this? i've came up with an answer, let's see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After some research I found the answer for my issue. If someone else is having issue like this one, then in **app.component.ts** file you should add this lines.

```
constructor(private config: Config) {
    this.config.set("scrollPadding", false);
    this.config.set("scrollAssist", false);
    this.config.set("autoFocusAssist", true);

    this.config.set("android", "scrollAssist", true );
    this.config.set("android", "autoFocusAssist", "delay");
}
```

this solved my problem for iOS and Android.

Comment: This solution is working for ios but in android the header is still fixed to top.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ion-input` like it's in the docs, inside a ion-item.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

if you don't want a `ion-label` just remove it and add `item-content` as a attribute to `ion-input`.

When you use `ion-item` Ionic automatically adds some classes and components where it places the input inside, maybe the lack of this component is causing your screen to bump when it's unecessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@djumerko is right. Just a little change.

Here is what works for me:

```
  this.config.set("ios", "scrollPadding", false);
  this.config.set("ios", "scrollAssist", false);
  this.config.set("ios", "autoFocusAssist", true);

  this.config.set("android", "scrollAssist", true );
  this.config.set("android", "autoFocusAssist", "delay");
```